# HTML Align Text to Bottom of Button with Images

Tags: html, css, text-alignment, text-align

I have square buttons that are 198px-198px. Each button has an image and text underneath. Since not all images are square, I set max-width and max-height to 128px for all images so that they scale proportionally. Unfortunately, I can't align the text to the bottom center anymore.

I cannot use `padding-top: 65px` which solved some other SO questions because the image has a variable height.

I tried `position: absolute; top: 180px` in a span for the text, but I can't get it to center after that (can't just specify `left: 10px` because the text has variable length)

Thanks for your help.

Here is a JSFiddle https://jsfiddle.net/vbgg3keu/3/  (Note: You can expand the width of the output pane so that all the buttons line up on the same line)

HTML:

```
<button class="square-button">
<img class="small-img" src="https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png"/><br/>

<span class="button-text">This text is too high</span>
</button>

<button class="square-button">
<img class="small-img" src="http://etc.usf.edu/clipart/36400/36459/ruler1_36459_lg.gif"/><br/>

<span class="button-text">This text is too high</span>
</button>

<button class="square-button">
<img class="small-img" src="https://tall.life/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/Giraffe.jpg"/><br/>

<span class="button-text">This text is the correct height</span>
</button>

<button class="square-button">
<img class="small-img" src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/dB3Dvgf3VIglusoGJAfpNUAANhTXW8K9mvIsiIPkhJUAbAKGKJcEMPTf0mkSexzLM5o=w300"/><br/>

<span class="button-text">This text is the correct height</span>
</button>
```

CSS:

```
.square-button {
  width: 198px;
  height: 198px;
  float: left;
}
.small-img {
    max-width: 128px;
  max-height: 128px;
}

.button-text {
  // this doesn't work because now I can't center the text
  //position: absolute;
  //top: 180px;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you can do is set your square-button class to position relative and use percentages to place the text while spanning the width to 100%:

https://jsfiddle.net/vbgg3keu/4/

```
.button-text {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 5%;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0%;
}

.square-button {
  width: 198px;
  height: 198px;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
}
```

Comment: Works perfect for the example case I posted! Thanks. What about the case where there's a bit more text? For example, I updated the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/vbgg3keu/6/ where one of the buttons' text spans 3 lines. Is there any way to move the image higher? I tried adding in the same stuff in the image css: `  position: absolute;
  top: 0%;
  left: 0%;` but it lost its centering

Comment: well right now you have a fixed height for the square and the image, so you would have to make those percentages

Comment: nvm I fixed it with `margin-top: -50px;` for the image. There's a lot of extra space above the image. Thanks for the above solution!

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code:

```css
.square-button {
    width: 198px;
    height: 198px;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
}
.small-img {
    max-width: 128px;
    max-height: 128px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
}

.button-text {
    position: absolute;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    bottom: 10px;
    width: 100%;
    left: 50%;
}
```

At https://jsfiddle.net/vbgg3keu/10/